# Define C# preprocessor symbol in NuGet package

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget, preprocessor

Can a NuGet package define a preprocessor symbol for the consuming project? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your package (`My.ExamplePackage`) contains an MSBuild file named like the package name + `.targets` in the build directory (so `build\MyExamplePackage.targets`), you can use it to amend the `DefineConstants` property that may have been set to defaults or reset in the project:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_PREPOCESSOR_SYMBOL</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

While the package can contain both a `.props` and `.targets` file, the `.targets` file will be imported after the main body of the csproj file being built so if it the project re-sets `DefineConstants` (meaning not adding to it by prepending `$(DefineConstant);`), the `.targtes` file has a chance of adding to this property.